# How to add jars on hive shell in a java application

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hdfs

i am trying to add jar on the hive shell. I am aware of the global option on the server but my requirement is to add them per session on the hive shell.
I have used this [class](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem) for the hdfs dfs commands to add the jars to the hdfs file system

This is what i have tried:

Created a folder on the hdfs /tmp
Add the file to hdfs filesystem using FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile [method](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#copyFromLocalFile-boolean-boolean-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-)
(equivalent to the hdfs dfs -put myjar.jar /tmp

Set permissions on the file on fhe fs file system

Check that the jar was loaded to hdfs using the getFileSystem [method](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#getFileStatus-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-)

List files on the fs FileSystem using [listFiles](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#listFiles-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-boolean-) to confirm the jars are there.

This works and I have the jars loaded to hdfs but i cannot add jars to the hive session

When i am trying to add it in the hive shell, i am doing the following:

```
statement = setStmt(createStatement(getConnection()));
query = "add jar " + path;
statement.execute(query);
```

I am getting this error [For example path of /tmp/myjar.jar]:

```
Error while processing statement: /tmp/myjar.jar does not exist
```

Other permutations on the path such as

```
query = "add jar hdfs://<host>:<port>" + path;
query = "add jar <host>:<port>" + path;
```

results with an error.

command to list jars works (with no results)

```
query = "list jars";
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
```

Comment: hi?? have you solve this problem? are you trying to register a custom udf??

Comment: there is a way to register custom functions in hive.. I'd like to tell you?

Comment: referring to serde jars

Comment: I was. thinking, you can use the `add jar` statement to add a jar function in hive due to I guess you were trying to define a new hive udf function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue

The process failed because of the configuration of the [FileSystem](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html).
This object is where we upload the jars to, before adding them on the session.

This is how you init the FileSystem 
`FileSystem fs = FileSystem.newInstance(conf);`

The object conf should have the properties of the hive server.

In order for the process to work, I needed to set the following parameter on the Configuration property
`conf.set("fs.defaultFS", hdfsDstStr);`